# .map() in reactJs is not returning anything

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components, jsx, react-props

i'm new to react and im trying to add render a list of items from an external SidebarData.js file (in the same root /components/..)
i'm not sure why my map function is not returning anything.
i get a list of elements thats correct, but the item.title and item.path seem not to render...

I feel there's a problem with the props.

I tried to write just

```
render(){
<h1>{SubmenuData[1].title}</h1>
}
```

and it works fine, but when i try to map on the full array, it doesn't seem to render anything. it renders the correct number of elements, but the title and path are not returning...

Here's my two components : Sidebar (Main one)

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData'
import Submenu from './Submenu'

    const Nav = styled.div`
        background: #f5f5f5;
        color: #7d7d7d;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:flex-start;
        height:100%;
        width:15%;
         
    `

const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav>
                {SidebarData.map((item, index)=>{
                    return <Submenu item={item} key={item.index} />
                })}
            </Nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Sidebar (Where i think there's a problem)
```

and Submenu

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const SidebarLink = styled(Link)`
    display: flex;
    color: #404040;
`

const SidebarLabel = styled.span`
    color:#000;
`

const Submenu = (item)=>{
    return (
        <SidebarLink to={item.path} >
                <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
        </SidebarLink>
)
}

export default Submenu
```

Comment: Are you able to console log `SidebarData`? And what does it look like

Comment: @Toxnyc its returning the correct output : the Array

Comment: Try to change this line 
const Submenu = (item)=>
to 
const Submenu = ({item}) =>
The function component in React accepts one parameter called props. If you want to access your props you either need to call props.item or destruct the props directly in the arrow function like in my suggested change.

Comment: @ElMehdiJilali Try to replace -  (item)=>{  WITH (this.props.item)=>{
in Submenu

Answer (score 0):

Your style of receiving props is mistake i guess. Destructure the props like:

```
const Submenu = ({item})=>{
    return (
        <SidebarLink to={item.path} >
                <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
        </SidebarLink>
)
}

export default Submenu
```